# Grav Page Routing in Twig Template in Multilanguage Setup

Tags: twig, grav

**Problem**

Using Grav CMS (v1.5.8) I want to redirect the user to other pages. The page  is a multilanguage setup and depending on the selected language, the route to the the base / start pages for the languages are simply:

`www.example.com/`

and

`www.example.com/en`

From a page, let's say `error`, I want to direct the user back to this start page. I realised this using the following code in the twig template:

`<a href="{{ uri.base }}/{{ grav.language.getLanguage }}" class="btn">`

which generates the correct url including the language string maintaining the current language.

**Question**

Is there any Grav API that handles generating / getting the root including the current language in a short way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that the redirect in a multi-language environment works if you use simply

`page.find('<the page you want to direct to>').url`

So in case of my question, redirecting to home would be

`<a href="{{ page.find('home') }}" class="btn">`

which resolves with the current language string.